# Flutter FCM Push notification Open rate always at Zero

Tags: flutter

I have Implemented FCM Push notification successfully using firebase_messaging 6.0.16. Device is getting Notification but Open rate in Firebase is always at zero even if notification is Opened. Is there any specific feature needs to be enabled.

Comment: Did you manage to find anything? Facing a similar issue in a production application

Comment: Wait for 1-2 days before checking open rate. I also suggest to download app from playstore and open notification to check if it is showing open rate

Comment: Thank you. I sent the notification today. Hope I get the statistics after a couple of days.